# Kivy - Adding elements in a Screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, multi-touch, kivy

```
import os,sys,random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen , SlideTransition
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Page(Screen):
    source = StringProperty()

class Imglayout(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self,**args):
        super(Imglayout,self).__init__(**args)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0,0,0,0)
            self.rect=Rectangle(size=self.size,pos=self.pos)


        self.rootpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))

        self.images=[]

        for img in os.listdir(self.rootpath+'/images'):
            self.images.append(self.rootpath+'/images/'+img)

        self.index=random.randint(0,len(self.images)-1)

        self.im=Image(source=self.images[self.index])
        self.im.keep_ratio= False
        self.im.allow_stretch = True
        #self.add_widget(self.im)

        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=SlideTransition())

        self.page1=Page(name='page1', source = self.images[self.index])
        self.page2=Page(name='page2', source = self.images[self.index+1])

        self.sm.add_widget(self.page1)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.page2)


        self.bind(size=self.updates,pos=self.updates)

    def updates(self,instance,value):
        self.rect.size=instance.size
        self.rect.pos=instance.pos

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
            if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                if(self.sm.current == 'page1'):
                    next='page2'
                    page=self.page2
                else:
                    next='page1'
                    page=self.page1

                self.index=(self.index+1)%len(self.images)

                page.source = self.images[self.index]
                page.background.scale = 1.0

                self.sm.transition=SlideTransition()
                self.sm.current = next

                anim = Animation(
                    scale=page.background.scale*1.3, 
                    duration=15.0
                )

                anim.start(page.background)

                return True


            return False



class MainTApp(App):


    def build(self):


        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',spacing=10)
        c = Imglayout()
        root.add_widget(c)

        cat=Button(text="Categories",size_hint=(1,.05))
        cat.bind(on_press=self.callback)
        root.add_widget(cat);

        return root

    def callback(self,value):
        print "CALLBACK CAT"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainTApp().run()
```

Taking some hints from [here](https://github.com/remip/kivy-apps/blob/master/slideshow/main.py) i made the above program. It says that Page does not have a background attribute in both my and the referenced code. Its kind of obvious since there is no background attribute. I thought it inherited that from Screen. I am trying to make a slideshow kind of thing. But i cant find any information on how to set the background of a screen.

And if i comment out everything with .background and run the app. click on the black space, then i start getting this error continuously on the terminal

```
[ERROR             ] [OSC         ] Address 127.0.0.1:3333 already in use, retry
 in 2 second
```

And i still dont get any background on the app.(its all black.)
and if i print self.sm.current on the touich function. Then i find that its always page1, it never changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kivy Guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html#adding-a-background-to-a-layout) explains how to add a background to a Widget. Briefly, you can do it in Python using the following code which binds to the position and size of the widget to make sure the background moves with the widget.

```
with widget_instance.canvas.before:
    Color(0, 1, 0, 1) # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
    self.rect = Rectangle(size=layout_instance.size,
                          pos=layout_instance.pos)
widget_instance.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

...
def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
    self.rect.pos = instance.pos
    self.rect.size = instance.size
```

Or you can do it more naturally with the kv language e.g.

```
MyWidget:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            # self here refers to the widget i.e screen
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```